# Como eliminar un elemento de un div

Tags: javascript, dom

Como puedo eliminar un elemento de un div contenedor, además quisiera que me respondieran sin la ayuda de jquery y sin los métodos de evento en las etiquetas ya que recien estoy empezando con javascript.

```js
let boton = document.querySelector(".boton")
let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor")
let enlace = document.getElementsByClassName(".enlace")

boton.addEventListener("click",() => {

    let li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerHTML = "Contenido " + Math.random() + "<a class='enlace'>x</a>"

    contenedor.appendChild(li)
})

enlace.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
    e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode); //ACÁ ME SALE ERROR
})
```

```css
body {
    font-size: sans-serif;
    max-width: 400px;
}
#contenedor li {
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
}
#contenedor li a {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Como agregar o eliminar elementos a una div</h1>

    <div id="contenedor">
        <li>Contenido 1<a>x</a></li>
        <li>Contenido 2<a>x</a></li>
    </div>

     <input class="boton" type="button" value="Agregar elemento" style="float: right;">

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo asi es lo que necesitas, el problema estaba en que estabas buscando en el elemento `<a>`eliminar su hijo

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let boton = document.querySelector(".boton")
  let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor")
  let enlaces = document.getElementsByClassName("enlace")

  boton.addEventListener("click",() => {

      let li = document.createElement("li")
      li.innerHTML = "Contenido " + Math.random() + "<a class='enlace'>x</a>";

      contenedor.appendChild(li);
      
      // se llama nuevamente el evento para que le asigne a cada enlace nuevo el evento de eliminar
      eliminar();
  })

  function eliminar(){
    // se recorren todos los elemntos a con clase .enlace
    for(var i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++){
      // se asigna el evento
      enlaces[i].onclick = function(e) {
        var content = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
        var li = e.target.parentNode;
        content.removeChild(li);
      };
    }
  }
// si no se llama al incializar el documento no se pueden eliminar los ya existentes
eliminar();
}
```

```css
body {
    font-size: sans-serif;
    max-width: 400px;
}
#contenedor li {
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
}
#contenedor li a {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Como agregar o eliminar elementos a una div</h1>

    <div id="contenedor">
        <li>Contenido 1<a class="enlace">x</a></li>
        <li>Contenido 2<a class="enlace">x</a></li>
    </div>

     <input class="boton" type="button" value="Agregar elemento" style="float: right;">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Daniel Mauricio Sánchez Ávila, me olvide preguntarte ¿Por qué solo funciona con "getElementsByClassName" y NO con "querySelectorAll"?

Comment: Realmente debería funcionar con `querySelectorAll` también, acabe de probar y funciona si declaramos la variable en la función `eliminar()`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let boton = document.querySelector(".boton");
let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor");
let enlace = document.querySelector("a"); 

boton.addEventListener("click",() => {

let li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = "Contenido " + Math.random() + "<a class='enlace'> x</a>";

contenedor.appendChild(li);
})

// creamos un click al contenedor ya que se proparagara al cada elemento dentro
// nota: no se le aplica al "a" directamente ya que no existe al momento de cargar el documento por ser dinamicos
contenedor.addEventListener("click",(e) => {
  // validamos que el target sea el "a" 
  if (e.target.nodeName == "A") {
e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode); //ACÁ salia error proque el target era "a" que no es hijo de "div". es hijo de "li"
  }
})
```

```css
body {
    font-size: sans-serif;
    max-width: 400px;
}
#contenedor li {
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    background: #ddd;
    list-style: none;
}
#contenedor li a {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Como agregar o eliminar elementos a una div</h1>

    <div id="contenedor">
        <li>Contenido 1<a>x</a></li>
        <li>Contenido 2<a>x</a></li>
    </div>

     <input class="boton" type="button" value="Agregar elemento" style="float: right;">

  </body>
</html>
```